# Object falling too fast in Matter-js engine

Tags: physics-engine, matter.js

I'm struggling to understand why my objects are falling so fast when using Matter-js. So I stripped everything back to the simplest example and it still happens.

```js
//import Matter from "matter-js";

let { Engine, World, Bodies } = Matter;

let engine = Engine.create();
let world = engine.world;

const ball = Bodies.circle(2, 2, 0.5);
Engine.run(engine);
World.add(world, ball);

const render = () => {
  console.log(ball.position, ball.velocity);
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
};

requestAnimationFrame(render);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/matter-js/0.14.2/matter.min.js" integrity="sha512-pi0tSRZdlNRZeANPwdAIHRAYg6gZZV6QlAiyHXn5TYqLzBKE9jlttO/QgYLMhISD6oNv2kPsVelx+n5nw0FqKA==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Apparently the distance units are metres, right? So I'd expect the ball to fall slower. In the example above, the Y coordinate hits 5000 within a couple of seconds.

What causes the ball to move so quickly?

Comment: "Apparently the distance units are metres" -- could you cite this? Most physics simulations are more "simulations" than "physics" so I'd be quite surprised if MJS actually aligned its simulation to something as precise and 'real world' as meters. The `y` position is in pixels, so all seems well here -- I'm not sure what you were expecting. Maybe if you render your ball, you'll see it falls quite naturally in a way the raw numbers don't really communicate.

Comment: I was going off a post from https://github.com/liabru/matter-js/issues/942 which recommends using SI units. So I suppose the question is more about whether there's a built in way to scale everything appropriately. Multiplying everything by 100 in the engine seems to make it behave more like I was expecting, but that carries the overhead of converting between the engine and renderer ie rendering everything at 0.01 scale. Any advice is appreciated :)

Comment: Thanks, that helps and I agree with Liabru's remarks. Why do you need/want to do this? What application context requires it? Maybe that information will help motivate the question and best solution.